# AngularJS resource + Slim Framework only gets a single data

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, slim

I'm creating a restful single page application using Slim Framework as my back end and AngularJS as my front end. So far, the Create, Retrieve All, and Delete is working but when I try to retrieve a single data, only a single field works. Here is my code:

**studentController.js**

```
angular
    .module('studentInfoApp')
    .factory('Student', Student)
    .controller('StudentsController', StudentsController)
    .config(config);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'StudentsController',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/student-list.html'
    });

}

function Student($resource) {
    //return $resource('/students/:id');
    return $resource("/students/:id", {}, {
    query: { method: "GET", isArray: true }
  });

}
function StudentsController(Student, $scope, $http) {

    $scope.inputForm = {};
    $scope.students = null;

    function clearInput() {
        $scope.inputForm = {
            fname: '',
            lname: '',
            age: '',
            email: ''
        }
    }

    function initStudents() {
        Student.query(function(data, headers) {
            $scope.students = data;
            $scope.studentsPanel = true;
            console.log(data);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    initStudents();

    $scope.editStudent = function(id) {
        Student.query({ id: id }, function(data, headers) {
            $scope.student = data;
            console.log(data);
            $scope.dataForm = true;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    }

}
```

**index.php (slim)**

```
$app->get('/students/:id', 'getStudent');
function getStudent($id) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM students where id=?");
        $query->execute(array($id));
        $stmt = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $data = json_encode($stmt);
        echo $data;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

**student-list.html**

```
<!--edit form-->
<div class="col s12" ng-show="dataForm" ng-repeat="x in student">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col l6 s12">
      <input id="first_name" value="{{ x.fname }}" type="text" class="validate" ng.model="editForm.fname">
      <label class="active" for="first_name">First Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col l6 s12">
      <input id="last_name" value="{{ x.lname }}" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="editForm.lname">
      <label class="active"  for="last_name">Last Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col l6 s12">
      <input id="email" value="{{ x.email }}" type="email" class="validate" ng-model="editForm.email">
      <label class="active"  for="email">E-mail Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col l6 s12">
      <input id="age" value="{{ x.age }}" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="editForm.age">
      <label class="active"  for="age">Age</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="updateStudent()">Submit
  <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light pink accent-3" ng-click="cancelEditStudent()">Cancel</button>
</div>
<!-- form -->
<table class="highlight responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="s in students | filter:searchStudent" ng-show="studentsPanel">
      <td>{{ s.fname }} {{ s.lname }}</td>
      <td>{{ s.age }}</td>
      <td>{{ s.email }}</td>
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="editStudent(s.id)">Edit</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="deleteStudent(s.id)">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I run it, I get this page:

[image]

And when I click `edit`, it shows:

[image]

As you can see, only the `first name` is being populated though everything is correct (field name, etc..) and the console returns no error.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be much appreciated. Got stuck already.